# How to plot the graph using base sytem in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to calculate number of movies in each category in base . Sample data is below :-

```
head(movies);
Rating Runtime Movieid
     R       50      1
    PG      100      2
     R       20      3
     G       10      4
    PG       16      5


plot(x=movies$V1,xlab="Rating",ylab=" of movies")
```

I get the graph using the above command.But i want to know how R plots the graph automatically on Y axis?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example): input, expected output.

Comment: Title and question in the description do not seem to be same?

Comment: Hello @Prradep  
  Rating Runtime Movieid
  R       50      1
  PG     100      2
  R       20      3
  G       10      4
  PG      16      5
This is the sample data.I want to calculate number of movies in each category

Answer (score 0):

try with `table()` function. For example:

```
data(iris)
table(iris$Species)
```

Hope that help ;)

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you .Plus i have chnaged my sample data for simplification.

Comment: i got the necessary result by using below command
plot(x=movies$V1,xlab="Rating",ylab=" of movies")

But i want to know how R calculates the Y axis?

Comment: To know how `R` calculates anything, the best source is, well, the source code. In your case it seems you're after function `plot.table` in file src/library/graphics/R/plot.R